# COUNT/GROUP BY query isn't working

Tags: php, mysql

I want to display a list of duplicate values from some unioned tables. My goal is to display TWO columns, the first listing duplicate values from the field URL, the second displaying the number of instances of each value, like this...

africa (2)

usa (4)

I can't figure out what the problem with my query is. When I try it in MySQL > SQL, it gives me an "empty result set." I double-checked the tables, and they both have a field named URL.

**UPDATE:** I erred in grouping URL on each individual table; there are no duplicate values in a particular table. I tried to fix it by moving the GROUP BY clause to the end of the query.

But I'm still doing something wrong. When I paste the query into SQL, it should display several URL's with two instances each. Instead, it displays "earth 471." On my web page, I see the error **Fatal error: [] operator not supported for strings**

Also, at the end of the code, how do I display the second column?

```
$stm = $pdo->prepare("SELECT *
FROM (
 SELECT URL, COUNT(*) c FROM gw_geog_political
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT URL, COUNT(*) c FROM gw_geog
) AS Combined
GROUP BY URL HAVING c > 1");
 $stm->execute(array(
));

while ($row = $stm->fetch())
{
 $URL[] = $row['URL'];
}

echo join( $URL, '' );
```

Comment: "*a really vague error message*"—did it not strike you that the actual error message might actually be quite significant, and of pivotal importance to anyone trying to solve this problem?

Comment: That's odd; I pasted it into MySQL again, but now I don't any error message at all. I must have made some minor change. However, I get an "empty result set," which explains why I get join(): invalid arguments passed I double-checked the tables; they both have a field named URL.

Comment: Can you show a small set of your tables, mainly what is on the URL field?

Comment: The primary duplicates are the names of continents. For example, both tables have the values 'africa', 'eurasia' and 'north-america' in the field URL. The matching values for the field Name are 'Africa', 'Eurasia' and 'North America'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. > When I try it in MySQL > SQL, it gives me an "empty result set." I double-checked the tables, and they both have a field named URL.

   Had one (or both) *not* had a column named `URL`, you would have seen [Error 1054](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_bad_field_error).  An empty resultset indicates that the query ran without problem, but produced no results.
2. > I erred in grouping URL on each individual table; there are no duplicate values in a particular table. I tried to fix it by moving the GROUP BY clause to the end of the query.
   >
   > But I'm still doing something wrong. When I paste the query into SQL, it should display several URL's with two instances each. Instead, it displays "earth 471."

   By moving `GROUP BY` to the outer query, you're left with inner queries that use the `COUNT()` aggregate function but have no `GROUP BY` clause of their own.  However, as documented under [GROUP BY (Aggregate) Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-functions.html):

   > If you use a group function in a statement containing no `GROUP BY` clause, it is equivalent to grouping on all rows.

   Therefore each constituent of the `UNION` will produce exactly *one* record (comprising an indeterminate `URL` and a count of the total number of records, of any `URL`, in the underlying table).

   That the grouping operation in the outer query results in resultset with only one record implies either that the indeterminate value of `URL` selected in each case happened to be the same (in which case the value of `c` is indeterminately selected from the two underlying results from the inner query), or else that one of the two tables is empty.

   To perform the aggregation in the outer query as you are attempting, you would need to move the `COUNT()` functions there too:

   ```sql
   SELECT   URL, COUNT(*) c
   FROM     (
              SELECT URL FROM gw_geog_political
            UNION ALL 
              SELECT URL FROM gw_geog
            ) AS Combined
   GROUP BY URL
   HAVING   c > 1
   ```

   However, since "there are no duplicate values in a particular table", what you're really trying to obtain is a list of URLs that appear in both tables (for which the `COUNT()` will always be two).  This can more directly be effected by means of an inner join:

   ```sql
   SELECT URL FROM gw_geog_political JOIN gw_geog USING (URL)
   ```

   If "duplicate values in a particular table" might exist in the future, you could simply add `DISTINCT` to the above query in order to remove them from the resultset—although to obtain the actual count would require a little more work:

   ```sql
   SELECT   URL, COUNT(DISTINCT gp.id) + COUNT(DISTINCT g.id) AS c
   FROM     gw_geog_political gp JOIN gw_geog g USING (URL)
   GROUP BY URL
   ```

   However, in this case, your original approach (grouping within the inner queries) would probably be more efficient—you just need to group *again* in the outer query, summing the inner counts:

   ```sql
   SELECT   URL, SUM(c) c
   FROM     (
              SELECT URL, COUNT(*) c FROM gw_geog_political GROUP BY URL
            UNION ALL 
              SELECT URL, COUNT(*) c FROM gw_geog GROUP BY URL
            ) AS Combined
   GROUP BY URL
   HAVING   c > 1
   ```
3. > On my web page, I see the error **Fatal error: [] operator not supported for strings**

   This is probably arising because a non-empty string is assigned to your `$URL` variable some time before the code snippet you have shown.  Consequently, the attempt to construct in it an array of result values using `$URL[] = ...` within the loop fails with the error that you see.  You should initialise your desired variable to an empty array prior to entering the loop, just to be sure:

   ```php
   $URL = array();
   while ($row = $stm->fetch())
   {
    $URL[] = $row['URL'];
   }
   ```

   Note that the same result can be achieved by using PDO's [`fetchAll()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) method:

   ```php
   $URL = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
   ```

   However it's generally a bad idea to load an entire resultset into a PHP array, since that can needlessly consume a lot of memory (and anyway you'll just have to loop a second time, over the resulting array, in order to operate upon it).  If you're able to perform your ultimate operation (output in this case) whilst fetching the results, then that will often be much more efficient:

   ```php
   while ($row = $stm->fetch())
   {
    echo $row['URL'], PHP_EOL;
   }
   ```
4. > Also, at the end of the code, how do I display the second column?

   As mentioned above, the count in each case will necessarily be *two*.  But if you want to use other columns from the resultset, you can modify the loop accordingly:

   ```php
   while ($row = $stm->fetch())
   {
    echo "$row[URL] ($row[c])", PHP_EOL;
   }
   ```

Comment: Got it; awesome tips!